# Need to pull RSS feed value based on value of XML node in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

Hi I've looked over these forums for a while but can't seem to find an answer.  If it has been answered before, I appreciate a link.

anyway, I'm trying to modify my RSS feed reader to include images from a Wordpress site.  With help other places here I was able to figure out how to deal with media:content nodes, however as Wordpress insists on using "Gravatar" images, I keep grabbing the wrong image;  I just need to be able to feed through an image where one exists."

Here's the XML:  (edited to include more of the original source file).
Edit note 2: I'm realizing that there's some inconsistent data coming from the blog itself regarding encoding of images, so I may have to get around that as well;  possibly if I could identify an image xpath where it is NOT the gravatar image such as this

```
<media:title type="html">fsclibrary</media:title>
```

Anyway, here's more of the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
>
    <channel>
    <title>Blog Title</title>
<atom:link href="http://fsclibrary.wordpress.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
 <link>http://fsclibrary.wordpress.com</link>


<item>
    <title>Worst winter ever? Find out with reliable climate data!</title>
    <link>http://fsclibrary.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/worst-winter-ever-find-out-with-reliable-climate-data/</link>
    <pubDate>Tue, 18 Feb 2014 14:11:37 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[fsulibrary]]></dc:creator>
     <description><![CDATA[Descriptive text here]]>
     </description>
    <media:content url="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/fa0ce8e825cafda53280958a7103a9b2?s=96&#38;d=identicon&#38;r=G" medium="image">
        <media:title type="html">fsclibrary</media:title>
    </media:content>

</item>
    <item>
        <title>Gold Medal Information about the Winter Olympics</title>
        <link>http://fsclibrary.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/gold-medal-information-about-the-winter-olympics/</link>
    <pubDate>Mon, 10 Feb 2014 17:05:28 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[fsulibrary]]></dc:creator>
        <description><![CDATA[Descriptive text for another item  here]]>
        </description>
        <media:content url="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/fa0ce8e825cafda53280958a7103a9b2?s=96&#38;d=identicon&#38;r=G" medium="image">
           <media:title type="html">fsclibrary</media:title>
        </media:content>
         <media:content url="http://fsclibrary.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/sochi.jpg?w=152" medium="image">
            <media:title type="html">Image</media:title>
        </media:content>
    </item>
<item>
    <title>Treasures from our Special Collections &#8211; Robert Cormier Correspondence</title>
    <link>http://fsclibrary.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/treasures-from-our-special-collections-robert-cormier-correspondence/</link>
    <pubDate>Wed, 04 Dec 2013 21:12:54 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[fsulibrary]]></dc:creator>
     <description><![CDATA[Descriptive text here for third item]]>
     </description>
     <media:content url="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/fa0ce8e825cafda53280958a7103a9b2?s=96&#38;d=identicon&#38;r=G" medium="image"
        <media:title type="html">fsclibrary</media:title>
     </media:content>

     <media:content url="http://fsclibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/cormier-letter-1.jpg?w=226" medium="image">
        <media:title type="html">Cormier Letter 1</media:title>
 </media:content>

</item>


    </channel>
  </rss>
</xml>
```

Here are my attempts at coding this (to no avail).  The problem is that I want to be able to skip the first one, but only display the image shown  where media:title has a value of "Image"

```
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $feedItem) {
    $i++;
    $myDate = ($feedItem->pubDate);
    $dateForm = explode(" ", $myDate);

    while  ($feedItem->children('media',true)->content->title == "Image") {

    $img =  $feedItem->children('media',true)->content->attributes();
    }  
    echo "<img src=\"" . $img['url']. "\">";
```

(etc.  this is just a snippet) Any help will be greatly appreciated

Edit:

The XML source is coming from here:  http://fsclibrary.wordpress.com/feed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fresh answer, this is how to display all `<item>`-nodes with the desired image-url(s).

**Method #1:** `xpath()`:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_string($x);
$i = 1;

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo "#$i: $item->title" . PHP_EOL;
    $i++;

    // xpath
    foreach ($item->xpath("//item[title = '$item->title']/media:content[media:title = 'Image']/@url") as $img) 
        echo "URL: $img" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Comment**: As `xpath()` returns the values from the whole XML, I included the `item/title`as condition to return only this item's children.

**Method #2:** iterating the "classic" way:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_string($x);
$i = 1;

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo "#$i: $item->title" . PHP_EOL;
    $i++;

   // classic
   foreach ($item->children("media", TRUE) as $img) {
       if ($img->title == 'Image') {
           foreach ($img->attributes() as $name => $value)
               if ($name == 'url') echo "URL: $value" . PHP_EOL;
       }
   }  
}
```

see it working: https://eval.in/132862

The XML source is not valid, I added a `>` in my example at `eval.in`

Comment: Thanks.  In the output, it's showing the sochi image twice under the second entry?

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry I got so busy;  after looking at your code I now understand.  Thank you so much;  this finally solved the problem.  I also very much appreciate seeing both the php and the xpath examples.

Answer (score 0):

`xpath`is your friend, it is like SQL for XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$url = (string)$xml->xpath("//media:title[text() = 'Image']/../@url")[0];
```

**EDIT**:
if your XML contains several nodes you want to select, do it like this:

```
$urls = $xml->xpath("//media:title[text() = 'Image']/../@url");

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo $url;
}
```

Comments:

- `//media:title`
  select all `<title>`-nodes with the namespace `media` wherever they occur in the tree...
- `[text() = 'Image']`
  where the content = `'Image'`...
- `/../@url`
  then go one step up and select the parent's attribute `url`
- `[0]`
  works with PHP >= 5.4 and selects the first element of the array returned by `xpath()`
- `(string)`
  force the result to string.

With PHP < 5.4, you'd do:

```
$url = $xml->xpath(...);
$url = (string)$url[0];
```

see it working: https://eval.in/131030

Comment: Thanks;  it's been a few years since I worked with xpath; I should have known this was the right approach.   It seems to be partially working, however still a problem:  This xml is coming from an RSS feed,  and it's definitely grabbing the first "Image" title (the xpath seems correct), repeating the same image every entry.

`foreach ($rss->channel->item as $feedItem) {
  $i++;
  $myDate = ($feedItem->pubDate);
  $dateForm = explode(" ", $myDate);
  $img =  (string)$feedItem->xpath("//media:title[text() = 'Image']/../@url")[0];

if (isset($img)) {
  echo "<img src=\"" . $img . "\">";
  }`

Comment: @nomistic: see my edit - no need to iterate over the XML, iterate over the `xpath`-results.

Comment: Thank you;  I can see how that would work, and I'm sorry to keep bugging you, but I"m now confused by the looping.   the variable `$feedItem`  already is part of a foreach loop.  when I run a separate foreach inside this, I end up getting _every_ image with that tag under every entry.   I tried taking the `$imgs =  $feedItem->xpath("//media:title[text() = 'Image']/../@url");` outside of the foreach but of course, `$feedItem` is only defined within it. I tried taking it out and tying it to $rss which comes from `$rss = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);` and got exactly the same result.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking that I need to combine both foreach statements.  Looking around I tried something like this:
`foreach (array_combine($rss->channel->item,$imgs) as $feedItem->$img)`  but of course it didn't work (error message) because I can't use `$rss->channel->item` as a varible.

Comment: @nomistic I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. What is the desired result?

Comment: it's basically just an RSS feed which is already working.  I can draw in the title and the description, but I wanted the images, but was having trouble.   The information you have provided is getting the images but each and every item (feed entry) is showing the same images, not the ones associated with them. 

The function calls the xml file:  
`$rss = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);`  and then loops through the contents:
`$i = 0;`
`foreach ($rss->channel->item as $feedItem) {`
`$i++;`
`echo <a href='$feedItem->link' title='$feedItem->title'>" . $feedItem->title . "</a>`  etc.

Comment: (It also includes the first 150 characters of the description, the same way it calls the title;  that's working fine)  I just wanted to add images, but because there are more than one (it comes from wordpress.  The issue is that there is already a `foreach` statement, and I'm not sure how to use the method you provided within it and have the specific image associated with each individual entry (not all entries have images).   I may have to rethink it.

Comment: @nomistic: I see, then do `$urls = $feedItem->xpath(...)` within the `foreach()`.

Comment: thanks, that really _should_ work but for some reason it's not looping.   First I get an "array to string" error, so I had to throw a [0] after the variable, but then it's not looping at all, it only brings back the first result.   It seems that for the xpath it is not seeing it as part of the "item" node;  it just seems to just check the entire file for the first entry and return the same thing for every item.  I can see no reason why `$feedItem->xpath("//media:title[text() = 'Image']/../@url")` is somehow being treated differently than `$feedItem->title`  Could the problem be the xpath?

Comment: What I really need is for it to look directly at the current node, and my understanding is that `// ` looks at the entire file.  I think I need something like `./media:title[text() = 'Image']/../@url` but that keeps giving an "undefined offset" error (though that may just denote an empty array), I'm thinking I need to start with `/` but I keep getting the error

Comment: @nomistic why don't you edit your question and post that complete XML.

Comment: I can, but there's a lot of it.  Should I just post the link?  It's this (view source to see the XML) [link](http://fsclibrary.wordpress.com/feed/)

Comment: @nomistic: simplify it down to the bare minimum, but keep the structure, and keep it valid. Like all the structure but two items with two children each. And keep the namespace definitions.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for being so attentive to this, I hope I'm not overcomplicating things.  Anyway, I have updated the xml code.